# How to parse JSON nested in list from bls.gov for use in react-chartjs-2

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, api, parsing

I'm trying to use the API provided by [bls.gov](https://www.bls.gov/developers/) - specifically https://api.bls.gov/publicAPI/v1/timeseries/data/CES0000000001 and break it down into individual variables(?) for use in [react-chartjs-2](https://github.com/jerairrest/react-chartjs-2).

I've managed to figure out how to fetch it, and add the raw JSON output to my site. What I am trying to do now is correctly parse the JSON so that it can be added in chart.js.

Here is the code that I used to fetch from the API. Currently it gives a popup alert on the site with the raw JSON from the GET request.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Testing extends Component {
    getDataUsingGet() {
        // Get request
        fetch('https://api.bls.gov/publicAPI/v1/timeseries/data/CES0000000001',{
            method: 'GET'
            // Request type
        })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        // If response is in json then in success
            .then((responseJson) => {
                //Success
                alert(JSON.stringify(responseJson));
                const obj = JSON.parse(responseJson);
                // ... Code for parsing to go here?

                console.log(responseJson)
            })
        // If response is not in json then throw error
            .catch((error) => {
                //Error
                alert(JSON.stringify(error))
                console.error(error)
            });
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                {/* Render the alert message in browser */}
                { this.getDataUsingGet() }
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Testing
```

This is the format of the JSON from the GET request.

```
{
    "status": "REQUEST_SUCCEEDED",
    "responseTime": 177,
    "message": [],
    "Results": {
        "series": [
            {
                "seriesID": "CES0000000001",
                "data": [
                    {
                        "year": "2020",
                        "period": "M03",
                        "periodName": "March",
                        "latest": "true",
                        "value": "151786",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {
                                "code": "P",
                                "text": "preliminary"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "2020",
                        "period": "M02",
                        "periodName": "February",
                        "value": "152487",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {
                                "code": "P",
                                "text": "preliminary"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
...
```

And finally, this is the code I'm using to generate the chart with `react-chartjs-2`. It's currently filled with sample data from the example chart.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Bar} from 'react-chartjs-2';

// TESTING FOR FETCHING API FROM WWW.BLS.GOV
// Data input for the RateChart chart.js generation -> 'data'
const data = {
    labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: 'US Unemployment Rate',
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,0.2)',
            borderColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
            borderWidth: 1,
            hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,0.4)',
            hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
            data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
        }
    ]
};

const RateChart = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Current unemployment</h2>
            <Bar
                data={data}
                width={100}
                height={50}
                options={{
                    responsive: true,
                    maintainAspectRatio: true
                }}
            />
        </div>
    );
}

export default RateChart;
```

**In summary:**
How do I take the JSON, break it down into `year`, `periodName`, and `value` so that they can be added to my `RateChart` component using jsx/javascript?

Thank you

Comment: If you think mine is the answer, if you could mark it with the checkmark that would be awesome!

Comment: Thank you for the help @Brockify - your answer was helpful for me understanding what was going on, but for this problem axios looks to be ideal.

Comment: you specifically asked for jsx/javascript solution, not with an additional package.

Comment: I suppose that is true, but I did not specify that it could not include an additional package in the solution. Ideally it would be the simplest solution. I've marked your answer as the solution because it does solve the problem in this context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this to parse that json. You will need to add null catches and such for when you don't get a successfull response, but based on what code you provided this should work.

Also, syntax wise, you should probably only return the response.json, and make the getDataUsingGet function asynchronus, await the fetch call, then handle the response! It is a much cleaner workflow than nesting .thens

```
 class Testing extends Component {
        getDataUsingGet() {
            // Get request
            fetch('https://api.bls.gov/publicAPI/v1/timeseries/data/CES0000000001',{
                method: 'GET'
                // Request type
            })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            // If response is in json then in success
                .then((responseJson) => {
                    //Success
                    alert(JSON.stringify(responseJson));
                    const obj = responseJson;
                    // ... Code for parsing to go here?
                    for(var i = 0; i < obj.Results.series.length; i++){
                        series = obj.Results.series[i];
                        for(var j = 0; j < series.data.length; j++){
                            console.log(series.data[j].year)
                            console.log(series.data[j].period)
                        }
                    }


                })
            // If response is not in json then throw error
                .catch((error) => {
                    //Error
                    alert(JSON.stringify(error))
                    console.error(error)
                });
        }

        render() {
            return(
                <div>
                    {/* Render the alert message in browser */}
                    { this.getDataUsingGet() }
                </div>
            );
        }
    }

    export default Testing
```

Comment: `series` is an unresolved variable and throws an error, changed to `var series`.
`const obj = JSON.parse(responseJson);` throws a `SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1 at JSON.parse`
Is JSON.parse an incorrect usage?

Comment: Fixed by changing `const obj = JSON.parse(responseJson);` to `const obj = responseJson;`. Since it's no longer a JSON string and already a javascript object.

Comment: Should not be `series.data[i].year`, should be `series.data[j].year` to return each item in the nested list.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
let result = json.Results.series.map((serie) =>
  serie.data.map(({ year, periodName, value }) => ({
    year,
    periodName,
    value,
  }))
);
```

```js
let json = {
  status: "REQUEST_SUCCEEDED",
  responseTime: 214,
  message: [],
  Results: {
    series: [{
      seriesID: "CES0000000001",
      data: [{
          year: "2020",
          period: "M03",
          periodName: "March",
          latest: "true",
          value: "151786",
          footnotes: [{
            code: "P",
            text: "preliminary",
          }, ],
        },
        {
          year: "2020",
          period: "M02",
          periodName: "February",
          value: "152487",
          footnotes: [{
            code: "P",
            text: "preliminary",
          }, ],
        },
        {
          year: "2020",
          period: "M01",
          periodName: "January",
          value: "152212",
          footnotes: [{}],
        },
        {
          year: "2019",
          period: "M12",
          periodName: "December",
          value: "151998",
          footnotes: [{}],
        },
        {
          year: "2019",
          period: "M11",
          periodName: "November",
          value: "151814",
          footnotes: [{}],
        },
        {
          year: "2019",
          period: "M10",
          periodName: "October",
          value: "151553",
          footnotes: [{}],
        },
        {
          year: "2019",
          period: "M09",
          periodName: "September",
          value: "151368",
          footnotes: [{}],
        },
        {
          year: "2019",
          period: "M08",
          periodName: "August",
          value: "151160",
          footnotes: [{}],
        },
        {
          year: "2019",
          period: "M07",
          periodName: "July",
          value: "150953",
          footnotes: [{}],
        },
        {
          year: "2019",
          period: "M06",
          periodName: "June",
          value: "150759",
          footnotes: [{}],
        },
        {
          year: "2019",
          period: "M05",
          periodName: "May",
          value: "150577",
          footnotes: [{}],
        },
        {
          year: "2019",
          period: "M04",
          periodName: "April",
          value: "150492",
          footnotes: [{}],
        },
        {
          year: "2019",
          period: "M03",
          periodName: "March",
          value: "150282",
          footnotes: [{}],
        },
        {
          year: "2019",
          period: "M02",
          periodName: "February",
          value: "150135",
          footnotes: [{}],
        },
        {
          year: "2019",
          period: "M01",
          periodName: "January",
          value: "150134",
          footnotes: [{}],
        },
        {
          year: "2018",
          period: "M12",
          periodName: "December",
          value: "149865",
          footnotes: [{}],
        },
        {
          year: "2018",
          period: "M11",
          periodName: "November",
          value: "149683",
          footnotes: [{}],
        },
        {
          year: "2018",
          period: "M10",
          periodName: "October",
          value: "149549",
          footnotes: [{}],
        },
        {
          year: "2018",
          period: "M09",
          periodName: "September",
          value: "149348",
          footnotes: [{}],
        },
        {
          year: "2018",
          period: "M08",
          periodName: "August",
          value: "149268",
          footnotes: [{}],
        },
        {
          year: "2018",
          period: "M07",
          periodName: "July",
          value: "149024",
          footnotes: [{}],
        },
        {
          year: "2018",
          period: "M06",
          periodName: "June",
          value: "148888",
          footnotes: [{}],
        },
        {
          year: "2018",
          period: "M05",
          periodName: "May",
          value: "148669",
          footnotes: [{}],
        },
        {
          year: "2018",
          period: "M04",
          periodName: "April",
          value: "148391",
          footnotes: [{}],
        },
        {
          year: "2018",
          period: "M03",
          periodName: "March",
          value: "148254",
          footnotes: [{}],
        },
        {
          year: "2018",
          period: "M02",
          periodName: "February",
          value: "148078",
          footnotes: [{}],
        },
        {
          year: "2018",
          period: "M01",
          periodName: "January",
          value: "147672",
          footnotes: [{}],
        },
      ],
    }, ],
  },
};

let result = json.Results.series.map((serie) =>
  serie.data.map(({
    year,
    periodName,
    value
  }) => ({
    year,
    periodName,
    value,
  }))
);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This would be assuming there will only be 1 item in the Results.series

Comment: Good catch, I've updated my answer which will work now for any number of series.

Answer (score 1):

const obj = {}

```
axios.get('https://api.bls.gov/publicAPI/v1/timeseries/data/CES0000000001')
      .then(function(response){
      const res = response.data.Results.series[0].data

      res.map(data=>{
        obj.period = data.period // same for the rest
      })
      });
```

Comment: For this particular problem, using axios looks like a better option than what I was doing to solve the problem. I was able to get this solution to work while the others required additional complexity.

Comment: this solution unfortunately will not account for multiple series data, you would need to double map this for this to be a correct solution. response.data.Results.series.length may be greater than 0